# javascript or jquery function for deleting graph using onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used rickshaw library for plotting graphs. In that the legend part is there. I have also used button on the legend to delete graph. That means when I click on close button the respected graph should get deleted. But I am unable to do this. Is there any JavaScript or jQuery function to do this? Please help me finding the solution for this. Onclick event.. JavaScript function for deletion of graph

This is my code for plotting graph using rickshaw library...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample-Rickshaw example</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rickshaw.min.css">
<script src="vendor/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/d3.layout.min.js"></script>
<script src="rickshaw.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
// CSS part
<style>
#chart_container {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#chart {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 40px;
}
#y_axis {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 40px;
}
#legend {
        display: oneline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
#close_box {
        btn_size:large;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
      font-size:small ; font-weight: bold; 
      float: right; color: #666; 
      display: block; text-decoration: none; 
      border: 2px solid #666; 
      padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;

}
</style>
// actual code
<body>

<div id="chart_container">
        <div id="y_axis"></div>
        <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
</head>


<div id="chart">
</div>
<div id="legend">

<FORM>
<INPUT type="button" value="x" onclick="remove graph">Remove Graph
</FORM>
</div>

// script for plotting data//
<script>
var palette = new Rickshaw.Color.Palette();

var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
        element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
        width: 550,
        height: 250,
        series: [

                {

                        name: "Northeast",
                        data: [ { x: -1893456000, y: 25868573 }, { x: -1577923200, y: 29662053 }, { x: -1262304000, y: 34427091 }, { x: -946771200, y: 35976777 }, { x: -631152000, y: 39477986 }, { x: -315619200, y: 44677819 }, { x: 0, y: 49040703 }, { x: 315532800, y: 49135283 }, { x: 631152000, y: 50809229 }, { x: 946684800, y: 53594378 }, { x: 1262304000, y: 55317240 } ],
                        color: palette.color(),


                }
        ]
} );

var x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( { graph: graph } );

var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
        graph: graph,
        orientation: 'left',
        tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
        element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
} );

var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
        element: document.querySelector('#legend'),
        graph: graph
} );

graph.render();

// jquery function 
$('#legend').on('click','.button',function(e){
    $(this).remove(graph);
    e.preventdefault
});

/*
$('#legend').on('click', function(e){ 
   $('#legend').remove();  // or do something else
   e.preventDefault();
}
*/

</script>
//Html tags
</body>
</html>
```

This is my whole code for plotting graph and respected legend.. commented part in the code is for deletion part.Is there any JavaScript or jQuery function to do this? Please help me finding the solution for this. Onclick event.. JavaScript function for deletion of graph`

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't you be deleting the chart layer?
$('#chart').remove(); or something similar, the onclick function you are applying to is over the #legend element which i suppose isn't the full chart, i mean that the $(this) will refer to the legend element which i imagine is a child of #chart

Comment: Tried that also.. But still the same problem. Is there any oother solution to fix this problem?? If yes please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript error console complains about multiple things in your code. Perhaps take some time to find your errors yourself before you implement my changes. **Always have the error console open when you are coding something in JavaScript!**

---

To get your code working:

In the onclick-attribute something in JavaScript is expected. Instead of:

```
<!-- this is invalid, not a method call, not an initialization, in onclick ... -->
<INPUT type="button" value="x" onclick="remove graph">Remove Graph
```

put

```
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="removegraph()" />Remove Graph
```

**Notice that I also ended the tag with />. Pay attention that all the tags are closed correctly!**

---

When I analyzed the elements on the website, I noticed that the graph isn't printed in the graph div, but uses the chart_container. To change this behavior I edited the parameters of the graph:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: $("#chart")[0], // I changed this line because this was obviously not working
    width: 550,
    height: 250,
    series: [{
        name: "Northeast",
        data: [ { x: -1893456000, y: 25868573 }, { x: -1577923200, y: 29662053 }, { x: -1262304000, y: 34427091 }, { x: -946771200, y: 35976777 }, { x: -631152000, y: 39477986 }, { x: -315619200, y: 44677819 }, { x: 0, y: 49040703 }, { x: 315532800, y: 49135283 }, { x: 631152000, y: 50809229 }, { x: 946684800, y: 53594378 }, { x: 1262304000, y: 55317240 } ],
        color: palette.color()
    }]
});
```

---

Replace your method

```
// jquery function 
$('#legend').on('click','.button',function(e){
    $(this).remove(graph);
    e.preventdefault // this line throws an error, because there is no ; and it is not a method-call nor an initialization or anything
});
```

with

```
// we've defined before, that this method is called when you click on the button X
function removegraph()
{
    $("#chart").remove() ;
    // uncomment the following lines, if you want to remove also the chart_container and the legend
    // $("#chart_container").remove() ;
    // $("#legend").remove() ;
}
```

---

**Also pay attention that you open and close the tags in the correct order, for example:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This isn't correct in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was very helpful. But another question i wanted to ask. Which function will be helpful for deleting metric data of graph on demand i.e onclick event. Means when i click on close button along with graph the respected data should also get deleted. Please help me in that..

Comment: @user3301256 If I understand you correctly you want to delete also the scale when you click on the button. This can be achieved when you also delete the chart_container-div. Put the following line in your removegraph()-function: `$("#chart_container").remove() ;`. I have already mentioned this in my answer. (If you don't mean this, please concrete your problem.)

Comment: @user3301256 Or if you really want to delete only the data of the graph, have a look on this example: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html

Comment: I have already used this function. But still i am unable to delete the data by which it is plotting the graph. I want to delete the input given to the graph by simply clicking on a button.